# WebSQL and MySQL synchronize

Tags: mysql, html, synchronization, web-sql

My HTML5 application stores all the local data in `WebSQL`. My server are using `PHP` and `MySQL`. Is there a method to synchronize the data both in local `WebSQL` and remote `MySQL`? Thanks very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to automatically synchronize a local WebSql database (SQLite of the browser) with a server should be this repo [WebSqlSync](https://github.com/orbitaloop/WebSqlSync).

**Features :**

- 2 way sync : client <-> server
- Incremental synchronization (send only the necessary data)
- Works offline. All data changes are tracked and synchronized with the
  server once the connection returns
- Support for replicating changes to multiple devices
- Support for Basic Authentication
- works with any JS web app or phonegap app (iOS, Android, etc.),
  without changing your code
- only 4kb gziped (and no dependencies)
- MIT licence

**Installing :** 
Just copy the src/webSqlSync.js file in your project and include it in your html :

```
<script src="lib/webSqlSync.js" type="application/x-javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```